# Content placeholder for preloading

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to make content placeholder for preloading like this :

http://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html

Is there a way to do this layout background animation in android?

Comment: have you found the answer yet ?

Comment: This probably will help future coders https://medium.com/mindorks/android-design-shimmer-effect-fa7f74c68a93